# Java Modify element in list

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java, I apologize if I am not using the correct lingo.

A list is loaded from a text file

```
static List<Media> list=new ArrayList<>();;

public boolean LoadMedia(String path) {
try {
File myObj = new File(path);
Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
    while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
    String data = myReader.nextLine();
    String[] str = data.split("-");
    
    if (str[0].equals("EBook")) {
        list.add(new EBook(str[0], Integer.parseInt(str[1]), str[2], Integer.parseInt(str[3]), str[4], Boolean.parseBoolean(str[5])));
    } else if (str[0].equals("MusicCD")) {
        list.add(new MusicCD(str[0], Integer.parseInt(str[1]), str[2], Integer.parseInt(str[3]), str[4], Boolean.parseBoolean(str[5])));
    } else if(str[0].equals("MovieDVD")) {
        list.add(new MovieDVD(str[0], Integer.parseInt(str[1]), str[2], Integer.parseInt(str[3]), str[4], Boolean.parseBoolean(str[5])));

        }
        
    }
```

I have a Constructor in a class called media

```
public Media(String name, int id, String title, int year, String chapter, boolean available) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.year = year;
    this.chapter = chapter;
    this.available = available;
}
```

This gets output to a string

```
@Override
public String toString() {
        return name + " [id=" + this.id + " title=" + this.title + " chapters=" + this.chapter + " year=" + this.year + " available=" + this.available + "]\n";
}
```

When a User rents an item:

```
public void rentMedia(int id) {
    for(Media mediaById : list ) {
        if(mediaById.getId()==id) {
            if(mediaById.isAvailable()) {
                System.out.println("media successfully rented out ");
                
                // some code here to update Boolean from true to false

            } else { 
                System.out.println("Media with id="+id+" is not available for rent ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the output is loaded again I would like for the output to now say false

I have tired list.set however get the following error:

```
list.set(5, false);

The method set(int, Media) in the type List<Media> is not applicable for the arguments (int, boolean)
```

As mentioned by Louis Wasserman and Traian GEICU

```
list.get(5).setAvailable(false);
```

Required me to create a setAvailable see below

```
public void rentMedia(int id) {
    for(Media mediaById : list ) {
        if(mediaById.getId()==id) {
            if(mediaById.isAvailable()) {
                System.out.println("media successfully rented out ");
                System.out.print(mediaById.toString());
                list.get(5).setAvailable(false);
            } else { 
                System.out.println("Media with id="+id+" is not available for rent ");
            }
        }
    }
}

public boolean setAvailable(boolean b) {
    available = false;
    return available;
}
```

Which threw an error

```
EBook [id=121 title=Shadow and Bone chapters=20 year=2012 available=true]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 2
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
at Manager.rentMedia(Manager.java:82)
at FinalProject.main(FinalProject.java:91)
```

Setting the index to something below 2 still did not change the true to false, not that it would but what I was hoping to see was one of the indexes change to false or get an error.

```
list.get(1).setAvailable(false);
```

Output:

```
Enter media id :
121
media successfully rented out 
EBook [id=121 title=Shadow and Bone chapters=20 year=2012 available=true]
```

Please see screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `list.get(5).setAvailable(false);`?

Comment: `list.set(5, false);` should be invoked with as instance of Media. `list.set(5, new Media("name" ... , false)`. Now think if is more advantageous to `replace and Object with new one` just for update one field, or maybe use `get` to retrieve object and just update the field.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I made an edit to the OP, I tried to post as a comment however did not make any sense. Thank you

Comment: In rent media you should update with an appropriate id : `list.get(id).setAvailable(false);` also `setAvailable` should be placed on `Media`.(related to current record) . Mainly even if is not recommended to update fields directly you could check also with  `list.get(id).available =false` (assume field is public)

Comment: also in `list.get(id)` should reflect position stored on `List` and not `id of Media`. So you could try with `mediaById.setAvailable(false);` (placed directly on desired list element)

Comment: Your `setAvailable` method is broken: It completely ignores its argument, always sets available to false regardless of argument, and then for some bizarre reason returns `false`. You just want `this.available = available;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could be helpful.

```
class TestUpdate{
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Media> l = new ArrayList<Media>();
        l.add(new Media("name", 10, "t1",2020,"C1", true));
        l.add(new Media("name", 20, "t2",2021,"C2", true));
        updateAvailable(l, 10);
        l.forEach(System.out::println);
        
        //update directly on list index 1 _ id=20
        l.get(1).available = false;
        l.forEach(System.out::println);
        
    }
    public static void updateAvailable(List<Media> list,int id)
    {
        for(Media media:list)
        {
            if(media.getId()==id)
            {
                media.setAvailable(false);
            }
        }
    }
    static class Media
    {
        private String name;
        private int id;
        private String title;
        private int year;
        private String chapter;
        public boolean available;

        public Media(String name, int id, String title, int year, 
                     String chapter, boolean available) {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.year = year;
            this.chapter = chapter;
            this.available = available;
        }

        public boolean isAvailable() {
            return available;
        }

        public void setAvailable(boolean available) {
            this.available = available;
        }
        
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
                return name + " [id=" + this.id + " title=" + this.title +
                       " chapters=" + this.chapter + " year=" + this.year + 
                       " available=" + this.available + "]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
name [id=10 title=t1 chapters=C1 year=2020 available=false]
name [id=20 title=t2 chapters=C2 year=2021 available=true]

name [id=10 title=t1 chapters=C1 year=2020 available=false]
name [id=20 title=t2 chapters=C2 year=2021 available=false]
```